# Stream CopyTo() method in c# not working as I want it to

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

What am I doing Wrong ?. This is my code snippet below:

```
PhotoResult e;
using (var filebytes = new MemoryStream())
            {
                    e.ChosenPhoto.CopyTo(filebytes);

                    Debug.WriteLine(e.ChosenPhoto.Length); // Outputs the correct length
                    Debug.WriteLine(filebytes.Length);  //Outputs 0

              }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely, you need to reset the position of `e.ChosenPhoto` before performing the copy:

```
e.ChosenPhoto.Position = 0;
```

[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx) states:

> Copying begins **at the current position** in the current stream